# WPF: ListView.SelectedItem when Cell has ScrollBar

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, mvvm

I have a problem in WPF.
So, double click works good with simple cells. But column, where I use ScrollBar doesnt react. How it is possible to handle those cells?

Here is my code:

```
<ListView>
    <GridView>
        <GridViewColumn Header="ColumnWithScroll" IsStretch="True">
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="SimpleItems">
                    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"                                                
                                  Name="Scroller" MaxHeight="200">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding TextBind}">
                        </TextBlock>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn>
        <GridViewColumn Header="Header" Width="150">
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Smth}" 
                               TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView.Columns>
    </GridView>
    <ListView.InputBindings>
        <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftDoubleClick" Command="{Binding SomeCommand}"/>
    </ListView.InputBindings>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Can you add more details please, what you want and what is not working

Comment: In a table(ListView) there are two columns. I want to handle double click. But the column, where I use scroll bar in cells doesnt react to double click. Simple column works good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:
Just set the property Focucable="False" of ScrollViewer